# Power expansion in terms of a fraction of two variables

Tags: series-expansion

I have the following complicated expression:

```
(3 (Sqrt[6] a^13 + a^12 e0 + Sqrt[6] a^11 e0^2 + a^10 e0^3 + Sqrt[6] a^9 e0^4 - 
  a^8 e0^5 - Sqrt[6] a^7 e0^6 - a^6 e0^7 + Sqrt[6] a^5 e0^8 - a^4 e0^9 - 
  Sqrt[6] a^3 e0^10 + a^2 e0^11 -Sqrt[6] a e0^12 + e0^13)) / 
(256 e0 (a^6 + Sqrt[6] a^5 e0 + a^4 e0^2 + Sqrt[6] a^3 e0^3 - a^2 e0^4 + 
  Sqrt[6] a e0^5 - e0^6)^2)
```

The numbers are huge and not very important. In fact, I am only interested in the behavior of the expression in the limit $a/e_0 \to 0$, so I would like to write it as a series of the form

```
constant + A (a/e_0) + O((a/e_0)^2),
```

for some coefficient A.

How can I do that automatically with Mathematica? I tried to use the Series function, but it cannot to an expansion for the variable $a/e_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsitude `a-> eps e0`

```
expr=expr = (3 (Sqrt[6] a^13 + a^12 e0 + Sqrt[6] a^11 e0^2 + a^10 e0^3 + 
Sqrt[6] a^9 e0^4 - a^8 e0^5 - Sqrt[6] a^7 e0^6 - a^6 e0^7 + 
Sqrt[6] a^5 e0^8 - a^4 e0^9 - Sqrt[6] a^3 e0^10 + a^2 e0^11 - 
Sqrt[6] a e0^12 + e0^13))/(256 e0 (a^6 + Sqrt[6] a^5 e0 + a^4 e0^2 + 
Sqrt[6] a^3 e0^3 - a^2 e0^4 + Sqrt[6] a e0^5 - e0^6)^2) /. a -> eps e0 // Simplify
```

which gives an expression in `eps`

For small `eps<<1` `Series` and resubstitution `eps-> a/e0` evaluates the expansion you are looking for:

```
Normal[Series[expr, {eps, 0, 2}]] /. eps -> a/e0
(*3/256 + (15 a^2)/(256 e0^2) + (3 Sqrt[3/2] a)/(128 e0)*)
```

Answer (score 0):

We give your expression a name: `y== expression`, then we add a second equation `x== a/e0` and eliminate a. Next, we solve for y to get the original function back. Finally we have an expression in x that we can expand around zero.

```
ex = (3 (Sqrt[6] a^13 + a^12 e0 + Sqrt[6] a^11 e0^2 + a^10 e0^3 + 
      Sqrt[6] a^9 e0^4 - a^8 e0^5 - Sqrt[6] a^7 e0^6 - a^6 e0^7 + 
      Sqrt[6] a^5 e0^8 - a^4 e0^9 - Sqrt[6] a^3 e0^10 + a^2 e0^11 - 
      Sqrt[6] a e0^12 + 
      e0^13))/(256 e0 (a^6 + Sqrt[6] a^5 e0 + a^4 e0^2 + 
       Sqrt[6] a^3 e0^3 - a^2 e0^4 + Sqrt[6] a e0^5 - e0^6)^2)

el = Eliminate[{y == ex, a/e0 == x}, a]

yx = y /. Solve[el, y]

Series[yx, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]